# Scene's network objects are disabled when building server separately

Tags: unity, mirror-networking

If one of the clients is also the server then this situation does not happen and networked scene objects are visible. But when building the server separately and then when a client is connected, all the network objects are disabled. I have read the documentation but still can't figure it out. I am loading the level scene additively. Here is the related documentation:

> Scene-based Network Game Objects
>
> You can also network game objects that are saved as part of your Scene (for example, environmental props). Networking game objects makes them behave slightly differently, because you need to have them spawn across the network.
> When building your game, Unity disables all Scene-based game objects with Network Identity components. When a client connects to the server, the server sends spawn messages to tell the client which Scene game objects to enable and what their most up-to-date state information is. This ensures the client’s game does not contain game objects at incorrect locations when they start playing, or that Unity does not spawn and immediately destroy game objects on connection (for example, if an event removed the game object before that client connected). See Networked Scene Game Objects for more information.

<sup>From [Network Identity](https://mirror-networking.com/docs/Articles/Components/NetworkIdentity.html)</sup>

> Network Visibility
>
> Multiplayer games use the concept of network visibility to determine which players can see which game objects at any given time during game play. In a game that has a moving viewpoint and moving game objects, it’s common that players cannot see everything that is happening in the game at once.
> If a particular player, at a certain point in time during game play, cannot see most of the other players, non-player characters, or other moving or interactive things in your game, there is usually no need for the server to send information about those things to the player’s client.
> This can benefit your game in two ways:
>
> - It reduces the amount of data sent across the network between
>   players. This can help improve the responsiveness of your game, and
>   reduce bandwidth use. The bigger and more complex your multiplayer
>   game, the more important this issue is.
> - It also helps prevent some cheating. Since a player client does not
>   have information about things that can’t be seen, a hack on that
>   player’s computer cannot reveal the information.
>
> The idea of “visibility” in the context of networking doesn’t necessarily relate to whether game objects are directly visible on-screen. Instead, it relates to whether data should or shouldn’t be sent about the game object in question to a particular client. Put simply, if a client can’t ‘see’ an game object, it does not need to be sent information about that game object across the network. Ideally you want to limit the amount of data you are sending across the network to only what is necessary, because sending large amounts of unnecessary data across the network can cause network performance problems.
>
> However, it can be also be resource intensive or complex to determine accurately whether a game object truly visible to a given player, so it’s often a good idea to use a more simple calculation for the purposes of determining whether a player should be sent networked data about it - i.e. whether it is ‘Network Visible’. The balance you want to achieve when considering this is between the cost of the complexity of the calculation for determining the visibility, and the cost of sending more information than necessary over the network. A very simple way to calculate this is a distance (proximity) check, and Mirror provides a built-in component for this purpose.

<sup>From [Network Visibility](https://mirror-networking.com/docs/Articles/Guides/Visibility.html)</sup>

Comment: Do you spawn them or are they already in the scene?

Comment: They are already in the scene